# How to emphasize the purity of one class in neural network?

Tags: neural-network, keras

I'd like to use neural network to classify three classes A, B, C ( supervised ). The traditional criterion is cross entropy. But if I am more concerned about the fake rate of B->A, C->A ( B fake to A and C fake to A ) and the true rate of A->A (A survive rate). I'd like to suppress the fake rate as low as possible but the true rate can be small like fake rate=0.000001 but true rate=0.5.

Is there any way I can do ( like change the loss function or network structure?)

Comment: Can you be more clear? Are you saying that: "Predict B for expected A" and "Predict C for expected A" are much more important than all other mistakes in the predictions?

Comment: @Daniel Sorry for my poor English, I am a little confused by "Predict B for expected A". What I mean is that: The rate of B fake to be A and the rate of C fake to be A is much more important than other rates.( Please imagine a 3by3 confusion matrix, two elements of the nine are much more important than others ). For example, if the number of each class is 10K, but 200 B is classified to be A, so the fake rate of B to A is 200/10K = 2%.

Comment: I'm thinking of creating a custom loss function, making a product of the predicted vector with the transposed expected vector. This would create your 9 x 9 matrix. Then you find out which elements of this 9 x 9 are relevant, and you create a constant matrix (9x9), with weights. Big weights for what is important, small weights for the rest. Elementwise multiply by our other matrix and then apply a mean square sum or something like that (I would try to research that and add an answer, but time is short now.) - For help with operations: https://keras.io/backend/

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. I'll do some research on it! Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you say "B fake to be A", what is the true value (the expected) and what is the calculated value (the predicted)?

Comment: Hmmm... doesn't seem to be working great.... the model learns to say everything is A .

Comment: @Daniel sorry for the very late reply. When saying "B fake to be A", the true value is "B"( the expected) and the predicted value is "A". I am thinking some ways like tuning the weight ( it worked but I don't know why it works) and using two neural networks ( one follow another one, the first one acts like a pre selection, but I haven't try yet.).